# Embedding an $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of embedding an $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for specific values of $n$. The proof can be found [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=57246). I am stuck on what is meant by "the reflection with axis $e_{n+1}T'(v)$". What does that even in mean in $\mathbb{R}^n$? I know a reflection matrix in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an orthogonal matrix with determinant -1, but to reflect about an "axis" in $\mathbb{R}^n$, wouldn't you have to do so across a hyperplane? I'm not sure what is meant by reflection across a vector. Any help is much appreciated!!!

**Edit:** I believe that Henry is more than likely correct, so thanks! Now I am wondering how I would go about constructing the actual transformation $S$ in the proof? For example, could someone please give an explicit construction as described in the proof for $m = 9 = 3^2$ and $m = 10 = 1^2 + 3^2$? Thank you!

**Edit 2:** I've figured this all out. This will hopefully be in a paper soon... we'll see.

Comment: They might mean reflecting about the hyperplane that is the orthogonal complement to the given vector.